# Avoiding solder mask in certain region in Altium PCB design

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I want to have a region in my PCB without solder mask while the other regions should have solder mask. I am not sure how do I do it in Altium? Is it by having a *Solid (copper) Fill* in the *Top/Bottom Solder* layer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solder mask layer is a "negative", so to remove solder mask from an area, simply place any shape on desired "Top/Bottom Solder" layer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's placed over a copper pour, so you're getting the copper color rather than the core color in 3D mode.

Comment: Yes. Is that a problem?

Comment: Not at all, looks nice.